# Configuration of appium server

Tags: appium

> Checking if an update is available
>   Update not available
>   Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app  --app-pkg  --platform-name Android --platform-version 16 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   usage: main.js [-h] [-v] [--shell]
>                  [--localizable-strings-dir LOCALIZABLESTRINGSDIR] [--app APP]
>                  [--ipa IPA] [-U UDID] [-a ADDRESS] [-p PORT]
>                  [-ca CALLBACKADDRESS] [-cp CALLBACKPORT] [-bp BOOTSTRAPPORT]
>                  [-k] [-r BACKENDRETRIES] [--session-override] [--full-reset]
>                  [--no-reset] [-l] [-lt LAUNCHTIMEOUT] [-g LOG]
>                  [--log-level {info,info:debug,info:info,info:warn,info:error,warn,warn:debug,warn:info,warn:warn,warn:error,error,error:debug,error:info,error:warn,error:error,debug,debug:debug,debug:info,debug:warn,debug:error}]
>                  [--log-timestamp] [--local-timezone] [--log-no-colors]
>                  [-G WEBHOOK] [--native-instruments-lib]
>                  [--app-pkg ANDROIDPACKAGE] [--app-activity ANDROIDACTIVITY]
>                  [--app-wait-package ANDROIDWAITPACKAGE]
>                  [--app-wait-activity ANDROIDWAITACTIVITY]
>                  [--android-coverage ANDROIDCOVERAGE] [--avd AVD]
>                  [--avd-args AVDARGS]
>                  [--device-ready-timeout ANDROIDDEVICEREADYTIMEOUT] [--safari]
>                  [--device-name DEVICENAME] [--platform-name PLATFORMNAME]
>                  [--platform-version PLATFORMVERSION]
>                  [--automation-name AUTOMATIONNAME] [--browser-name BROWSERNAME]
>                  [--default-device] [--force-iphone] [--force-ipad]
>                  [--language LANGUAGE] [--locale LOCALE]
>                  [--calendar-format CALENDARFORMAT] [--orientation ORIENTATION]
>                  [--tracetemplate AUTOMATIONTRACETEMPLATEPATH]
>                  [--instruments INSTRUMENTSPATH] [--show-sim-log]
>                  [--show-ios-log] [--nodeconfig NODECONFIG] [-ra ROBOTADDRESS]
>                  [-rp ROBOTPORT] [--selendroid-port SELENDROIDPORT]
>                  [--chromedriver-port CHROMEDRIVERPORT]
>                  [--chromedriver-executable CHROMEDRIVEREXECUTABLE]
>                  [--use-keystore] [--keystore-path KEYSTOREPATH]
>                  [--keystore-password KEYSTOREPASSWORD] [--key-alias KEYALIAS]
>                  [--key-password KEYPASSWORD] [--show-config] [--no-perms-check]
>                  [--command-timeout DEFAULTCOMMANDTIMEOUT] [--keep-keychains]
>                  [--strict-caps] [--isolate-sim-device] [--tmp TMPDIR]
>                  [--trace-dir TRACEDIR] [--intent-action INTENTACTION]
>                  [--intent-category INTENTCATEGORY] [--intent-flags INTENTFLAGS]
>                  [--intent-args OPTIONALINTENTARGUMENTS]
>                  [--dont-stop-app-on-reset] [--debug-log-spacing]
>                  [--suppress-adb-kill-server] [--async-trace]
>
> main.js: error: argument "--app": Expected one argument. null
>
> Appium server process ended

suggest solution

Answer (score 0):

Your Appium application's Android settings have `App Path` and `Package` ticked enabled, but their values are empty.

You need to enable only one of these strategies:

`App Path` takes your apk file. This is seen in the log as `--app APP.apk`

---

`Package` takes your application's package name (must be pre-installed to the device). This is seen in the log as `--app-pkg ANDROIDPACKAGE`

`Launch Activity` takes your application's launch activity (required when launching with package name). This is seen in the log as `--app-activity ANDROIDACTIVITY`

Comment: thnx my dear friend Domestus